# Intent description in android

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Am working on an app that analyze some contents of an apk before installing. i was able to retrieve all intents filters in the apk, now am looking for a way to map each intent name to its android description.

Examples
for [android intent documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) , the following were mapped to a discription

> ACTION_SEND => Activity Action: Deliver some data to someone else.
>
> ACTION_SENDTO => Activity Action: Send a message to someone specified by the data.
>
> CATEGORY_LAUNCHER => Should be displayed in the top-level launcher.
>
> CATEGORY_DEFAULT => Set if the activity should be an option for the default action (center press) to perform on a piece of data.

Is there any function that i can programmatically supply the intent name to and will return the description

Comment: Intent actions and categories are simply strings. There is no description for these, except in the form of documentation.

Comment: oh, i see. so it seem I have to write the description myself , probably store it in an HashMap or database. what do you think @CommonsWare

Comment: Well, there are an infinite number of possible strings. :-) If you want to handle some of the basic ones, you're welcome to put some sort of mapping into your app, perhaps using the descriptions from the JavaDocs. Just be prepared to handle unexpected actions and categories.